# Angular gui before rendering

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im quite new to angular/ionic world. Im doing a mobile app that eventually will be transformed to native with phonegap.

As a newbie in angular, there is a thing that is not so clear for me. And I wonder if people that have developed mobile apps (actually, even those that developed ordinary webapps) in production can help me understand this simple thing:

When a page is loaded, it happens sometimes that for a few milliseconds, I can see the ugly parenthesis (brace/bracket) in the gui.

So if I have a page with:

```
<h1>{{myvar}}</h1>
```

There can be a extremly short time when I can see the text just as it is above:

```
{{myvar}}
```

but then it is replaced by the real value of {{myvar}}

So, whats the point? The point is that, to me, this is very ugly. Even if that will be dispalyed for 0,001 seconds, I still think this is ugly. I cant believe Im the only one that gets annoyed by this. Am I? If not, how does you as developer react? Do you try some workaround to hide the gui before angular is done with its job of modifying the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `ngCloak`. Which means that you need to add this directive to the HTML element, like that:

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

[Here are docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wondering why this is not a default behaviour in angular.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to avoid this is to use [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) instead of the braces:

```
<h1 ng-bind="myvar"></h1>
```